# How do I put a plotly express animation onto a static image

Tags: python, plotly-express

I have plotted an animated graph in plotly-express (of aeroplanes moving on a map) from a dataframe that looks similar to the following:

```
x    y    time    label
10   5    1       Virgin
15   10   2       Virgin
20   10   3       Virgin
25   20   4       Virgin
10   5    1       BA
5    -10  2       BA
-5   -10  3       BA
```

The code to plot the plotly-express animation looks similar to the following and it works great:

```
px.scatter(df, x = 'x', y = 'y',
              animation_frame='time', animation_group='label', text='label')
```

However, I now want to plot this animation onto a map and I can't figure out how to do it. To reiterate, I want the animation plotted with a map in the background so I can see where the aeroplanes are.

Answer (score 0):

To plot data onto a map with animation, you can use `scatter_geo`:

```py
import plotly.express as px

gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.scatter_geo(gapminder, locations="iso_alpha", color="continent",
                     hover_name="country", size="pop",
                     animation_frame="year", projection="natural earth")
fig.show()
```

[image]